# How to attach two XNA models together?

Tags: xna, 3d, xna-4.0

I go back on unsolved question I asked about attaching two models together, could you give me some help on this ?

For example, If I want to attach together Model1 (= Main model) & Model2 ? 
I have to get the transformation matrix of Model1 and after
get the Bone index on Model1 where I want to attach Model2 and then apply some transformation to attach Model2 to Model1

I wrote some code below about this, but It does not work at all !! (6th line of my code seems to be wrong !?)

```cs
Model1TransfoMatrix=New Matrix[Model1.Bones.Count];

Index=Model1.bone[x].Index;

foreach (ModelMesh mesh in Model2.Meshes)
{ 
  foreach(BasicEffect effect in mesh.effects)
  {
     matrix model2Transform = Matrix.CreateScale(0.1.0f)*Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(x,y,z);

     effect.World= model2Transform *Model1TransfoMatrix[Index];
     effect.view = camera.View;
     effect.Projection= camera.Projection;
   }
   mesh.draw();
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by attaching models together? I'm seeing two possibilities: an object 'held' by the first model, such as a sword, or an object that should be part of the first model, like a gun turret. Which is your intention?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite abstract.

I would suggest 2 methods.

1. using 3d redactor such as 3dmax or blender or whatever.
2. Draw second model using a SINGLE BONE absolute transform from model1.

It should look like:

```
Matrix[] Model1TransfoMatrix;
model1.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(Model1TransfoMatrix);
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in Model2.Meshes)
{ 
  foreach(BasicEffect effect in mesh.effects)
  {
     matrix model2Transform = Matrix.CreateScale(0.1.0f)*Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(x,y,z);

     effect.World= model2Transform *Model1TransfoMatrix[0]; //root bone index
     effect.view = camera.View;
     effect.Projection= camera.Projection;
   }
   mesh.draw();
 }
```

Comment: please do you can answer this ? ^^ : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45793/how-attach-a-model-with-another-model-on-a-specific-bone